# Angular NG0912 Warning: Component ID generation collision detected after upgrading to angular 17

Tags: angular, warnings, angular17, browser-console, versionupgrade

I recently upgraded my Angular project to version 17, and now I'm encountering many browser console warnings like the following messages.

> NG0912: Component ID generation collision detected. Components
> 'DevDashboardComponent' and 'DevDashboardComponent' with selector
> 'lib-dev-dashboard-page' generated the same component ID. To fix this,
> you can change the selector of one of those components or add an extra
> host attribute to force a different ID. Find more at
> https://angular.io/errors/NG0912

> NG0912: Component ID generation collision detected. Components
> 'ScrollerComponent' and 'ScrollerComponent' with selector
> 'datatable-scroller' generated the same component ID. To fix this, you
> can change the selector of one of those components or add an extra
> host attribute to force a different ID. Find more at
> https://angular.io/errors/NG0912

Despite having different selector IDs for each library in my Angular project, these warnings persist. These warnings didn't appear before the upgrade.

However, after building the project using `ng build` and running it, the warnings doesn't appear.

Is there any specific configuration or setting that needs to be adjusted after upgrading to Angular 17 to prevent this warning?

Comment: Might help to delete the angular cache folder ".angular" and try again

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Removing the .angular directory didn't have any effect.